# JavaScript: How to check if variable exists by variable name?

Tags: javascript

I am having this issue. I have a script that checks if variable exists, because some scripts load asyncronously, like FB for Facebook or twttr for Twitter.

```
function whenAvailable(name, callback, interval) {
    interval || (interval = 100); // ms
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ((window.hasOwnProperty && window.hasOwnProperty(name)) || window[name] || !!eval(name)) {
            return callback();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

Looks like this

```
if ((window.hasOwnProperty && window.hasOwnProperty(name)) || window[name] || !!eval(name))
```

does not work. IE throws error for 
eval(name) -- e.g. if name = 'FB', it says it can't eval 'FB' which is undefined.

`window.hasOwnProperty(name)` does not work if `name == 'twttr.widgets'`.

**Is there a universal and cross browser check for existence of var by var name?**

Comment: quick question, do those variables always exist in the scripts loaded?

Comment: There can't be a variable named `twttr.widgets`. There can be a variable named `twttr` which may have a property `widgets`, but hopefully you can see it's not as simple as "does this property exist"

Comment: Joseph - no, they may never exist.

Gareth - technically you're right but what I wanted needs to work with properties as well.

Comment: @Gareth: There can certainly be a property of `window` called `twttr.widgets`. It would be unusual, but it's perfectly legal. `window['twittr.widgets'] = "foo";`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you don't need that `eval` (you almost never do), you can index into a JavaScript object using a string and bracketed notation, e.g.:

```
window['FB'];
```

or

```
name = 'FB';
foo = window[name];
```

So to check:

```
if (typeof window[name] === "undefined")
```

...except that doesn't differentiate between the property not existing at all, or existing but having the value `undefined`.

or

```
if (name in window)
```

...but that checks the prototype as well as the object. It's fine for `window`, though.

> `window.hasOwnProperty(name)` does not work if `name == 'twttr.widgets'`.

Right, you have to break it up:

```
var index = 0,
    parts = name.split('.'), // doesn't handle [] notation
    result;
result = window;
index = 0;
try {
    while (typeof result !== "undefined" && result !== null && index < parts.length) {
        result = result[parts[index++]];
    }
}
catch (e) {
}
if (index < parts.length) {
    // Didn't find all of it
}
```

...or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I only changed if (index < parts.length) to if (index < parts.length || (typeof result == 'undefined' && result === undefined)) return false;

Comment: @SODA: Good deal. FWIW, if `typeof result == "undefined"` the odds are very high (though granted not 100% if you're dealing with cross-window stuff) that `result === undefined`, you can probably drop the second bit and just keep the typeof check. Also note that I included `result !== null` for a reason (typeof `null` is not `"undefined"` but if you try to dereference `null` with brackets, you'll get an exception).

Answer (score 3):

I've always just used things like:

```
if (window[name]) {
    return 'it exists';
} else {
    return 'nope';
}
```

EDIT: This works because if window[name] isn't there, the if determines `undefined` to be false.

Comment: No, in your case if I do var name = 'FB', window.name will return 'FB' but what I need is to return window['FB'] or window.FB

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

`if ('key' in object)`

so in your example

`if (name in window)`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `twttr.widgets` as well as `twttr`, something like:

```
var parts = name.split( '.' )
  ,  aVar = window;

while( parts.length ){
    aVar = aVar[ aVar.shift() ];
    return setTimeout( ... );
}

// aVar will now be your resolved variable
return callback();
```